# Postgres 9.4.4 query takes forever

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

We're running Postgres 9.4.4 on CentOS 6.5 and have a SELECT query that has worked for years, but stopped working and hangs after we upgraded from 9.2 (it took a while to notice it, so I don't know if it was immediately after we upgraded or not).

```
SELECT id || ':' || group_number AS uniq_id
FROM   table_one
WHERE  id || ':' || group_number NOT IN (
   SELECT id || ':' || group_number
   FROM table_two
   )
AND    id NOT IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM table_three
   WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days' 
   AND client_id > 0
   );
```

In all tables `id` is an integer, but is stored as `character varying (15)` (legacy system). `group_number` is stored as a `smallint`.

The sub-query for table_two returns about 2.5 million records. The sub-query for `table_three` returns about 2,500 records. Both return in about 1 second if run separately. But adding in either query (or both) as sub-queries causes the query to just hang indefinitely (for days, if we let it run).

I've seen others online with the same problem (query not returning when using `NOT IN`). `NOT IN` seems like such a straight forward sub-query.

We have plenty of hardware (384 GB RAM, Xeon 64 cores, 16 disk 15k RPM RAID 10).

1. Why is this happening? (ie. is this a major ongoing bug in Postgres?)
2. How can I fix / debug it in the meantime?

Here are the results of `EXPLAIN`:

```
QUERY PLAN
Index Only Scan using table_one_id_pk on table_one  (cost=19690.90..64045129699.10 rows=370064 width=9)
  Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND (NOT (SubPlan 1)))
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_three  (cost=2446.92..19686.74 rows=8159 width=7)
          Recheck Cond: (("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval)) AND (client_id > 0))
          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2446.92..2446.92 rows=8159 width=0)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_one_timestamp_idx  (cost=0.00..1040.00 rows=79941 width=0)
                      Index Cond: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fki_table_three_client_id  (cost=0.00..1406.05 rows=107978 width=0)
                      Index Cond: (client_id > 0)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..84813.75 rows=3436959 width=9)
          ->  Seq Scan on table_two  (cost=0.00..64593.79 rows=3436959 width=9)
```

My settings from `postgresql.conf`

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 24GB
temp_buffers = 8MB
work_mem = 96MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
cpu_tuple_cost = 0.0030
cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.0010
cpu_operator_cost = 0.0005
effective_cache_size = 128GB
from_collapse_limit = 4
join_collapse_limit = 4
```

#### UPDATE

I used the following method to adjust the `work_mem` just for this query:

```
BEGIN;
SET work_mem = '256MB';
-- query --
SET work_mem = default;
COMMIT;
```

Using `NOT IN` returned in 5 - 8 seconds (vs never with `work_mem = 96MB`).

Using `LEFT JOIN` returned in 13 - 14 seconds (vs 24 seconds with `work_mem = 96MB`).

So it looks like the **problem** was with `work_mem`, and using `LEFT JOIN` was just a workaround. However, the real problem is Postgres going for days with `work_mem = 96MB`.

With 16 x 15k SAS drives in RAID 10 we have very fast I/O, so even going to disc the query should have returned, just a bit slower.

**UPDATE 2**

Here are the results for EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the LEFT JOIN approach:

```
    QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=27318.56..351160.97 rows=728325 width=9) (actual time=9553.378..21247.202 rows=7 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=27318.47..176945.69 rows=1501249 width=9) (actual time=511.578..5479.549 rows=1478438 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: ((t1.id)::text = (t3.id)::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on table_one t1  (cost=0.00..143842.21 rows=1593403 width=9) (actual time=0.026..4369.804 rows=1485291 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=27289.76..27289.76 rows=8203 width=7) (actual time=511.518..511.518 rows=1286 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 51kB
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_three t3  (cost=1518.79..27289.76 rows=8203 width=7) (actual time=125.379..510.998 rows=1286 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (client_id > 0)
                     Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 104626
                     Heap Blocks: exact=16093
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fki_table_three_client_id  (cost=0.00..1518.38 rows=108195 width=0) (actual time=121.633..121.633 rows=122976 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (client_id > 0)
   ->  Index Only Scan using t_table_two_id2_idx on table_two t2  (cost=0.09..0.14 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1478438)
         Index Cond: ((id = (t1.id)::text) AND (group_number = t1.group_number))
         Heap Fetches: 143348
 Planning time: 30.527 ms
 Execution time: 21247.541 ms
(18 rows)

Time: 23697.256 ms
```

And here they are for the NOT EXISTS approach:

```
    QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=27318.56..351160.97 rows=728325 width=9) (actual time=5117.110..14061.838 rows=7 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=27318.47..176945.69 rows=1501249 width=9) (actual time=146.779..1254.400 rows=1478439 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: ((t1.id)::text = (t3.id)::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on table_one t1  (cost=0.00..143842.21 rows=1593403 width=9) (actual time=0.007..591.383 rows=1485291 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=27289.76..27289.76 rows=8203 width=7) (actual time=146.758..146.758 rows=1285 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 51kB
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_three t3  (cost=1518.79..27289.76 rows=8203 width=7) (actual time=17.586..146.330 rows=1285 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (client_id > 0)
                     Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 104627
                     Heap Blocks: exact=16093
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fki_table_one_client_id  (cost=0.00..1518.38 rows=108195 width=0) (actual time=14.415..14.415 rows=122976 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (client_id > 0)
   ->  Index Only Scan using t_table_two_id2_idx on table_two t2  (cost=0.09..0.14 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1478439)
         Index Cond: ((id = (t1.id)::text) AND (group_number = t1.group_number))
         Heap Fetches: 143348
 Planning time: 2.155 ms
 Execution time: 14062.014 ms
(18 rows)

Time: 14065.573 ms
```

Comment: First things first.  Can you run an `EXPLAIN` on the query, and post the results in an edit?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Try `... WHERE (id, group_number) NOT IN (select id, group_number from table_two) ... ` instead of using the concatenated values. That  might be able to use a combined index on the columns. You can also try to rewrite the `NOT IN` into a `NOT EXISTS` co-related subquery, sometimes that performs better.

Comment: OK, because you have a system with 384 GB of RAM, but you're having to run a `Recheck Condition` in SubPlan 2 makes me wonder: What did you set the `work_mem` to (in the `postgresql.conf` file) when you upgraded to 9.4.4?

Comment: I updated my post with settings from postgresql.conf (work_mem = 96MB).

Comment: With `work_mem = 256MB` using `... WHERE (id, group_number) NOT IN (select id, group_number from table_two) ...` was consistently 25% to 50% faster than using `... WHERE id || ':' || group_number NOT IN (SELECT id || ':' || group_number FROM table_two ...`.  Thanks

Comment: Please add relevant index definitions.

Comment: So in the end it was `work_mem`.  Glad to see it's fixed.

Comment: @Chris: `work_mem` helped to counter all the other problems in the query. It's not the solution, but another workaround - or just a helpful setting. BTW, bitmap index scans need to recheck conditions by design, that was unrelated to RAM being a bottleneck.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I can see right away what you mean; the re-written query is certainly better, and the `work_mem` solution is just a quick patch.  With respect to the recheck condition, a little investigation seems to indicate that the recheck condition is always printed in the `EXPLAIN`, but is actually only performed when `work_mem` is small enough that the bitmap becomes lossy. Thoughts?  http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/464F3C5D.2000700@enterprisedb.com

Comment: @Chris: All true, and Heikki is a first class source, but the link is a bit outdated (2007, pg 8.2). This was getting too big for a comment, and you are raising highly interesting points. So I posted a new question and answer to address the matter: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan. Feel free to add another answer with anything I might have missed.

Comment: Thanks for adding test runs with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. The result seems to favor my `NOT EXISTS` solution. But a closer look reveals identical query plans. The difference in performance may a caching effect. If you run either query a couple of times you should see similar performance for both. pg 9.4 seems to be smart enough to find the same query plan for either variant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you checked off usual suspects in the [wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) as [commented by @a_horse](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106126/postgres-9-4-4-query-takes-forever/106218#comment192924_106126).

Also see the spin-off addressing the discussion of bitmap index scans and the size of `work_mem`.

- ["Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan)

#### Query

This rewritten query should be ***substantially*** faster:

```
SELECT id || ':' || group_number AS uniq_id
    -- id::text || ':' || group_number AS uniq_id  -- with integer
FROM   table_one t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( 
   SELECT 1
   FROM   table_two t2
   WHERE  t2.id = t1.id
   AND    t2.group_number = t1.group_number
   ) 
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   table_three t3
   WHERE  t3.timestamp > NOW() - interval '30 days' 
   AND    t3.client_id > 0
   AND    t3.id = t1.id
   );
```

- The most important problem is comparing a concatenated string between `table_one` and `table_two`, which is generally more expensive than necessary and specifically **not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)**.
- Storing **integer numbers as strings is expensive nonsense**. You seem to be aware of that. Convert to `integer` if at all possible. If you only have valid integer numbers in the varchar column `id`, all you need to do is:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE table_one ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer USING id::int;
  ```

  And possibly the same for `table_two`.
- `NOT IN` carries a trap for **NULL values** on either side. That's why **`NOT EXISTS`** is almost always better. (Typically performs better on top of that.)

  - [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

#### Indexes

Either way, key to performance are matching indexes.

Be sure to have [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `table_one` and `table_two`:

```
CREATE INDEX t1_foo_idx ON table_one (id, group_number)
CREATE INDEX t2_foo_idx ON table_two (id, group_number)
```

Possibly allows [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).
With `integer` instead of `varchar`, these would be smaller and more efficient, yet:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

And I suggest a [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) multicolumn index on `table_three`:

```
CREATE INDEX t3_foo_idx ON table_three (timestamp, id)
WHERE  client_id > 0
AND    timestamp > '2015-06-07 0:0';
```

Usefulness deteriorates over time. Recreate the index with increased lower bound at opportune moments - which takes an exclusive lock on the table, so consider `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`. Detailed explanation:

- [Index optimization with dates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27928/index-optimization-with-dates/27929#27929)

You need to match the (updated) index condition in your queries. Add the condition even if that seems redundant. Like:

```
...
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   table_three t3
   WHERE  t3.timestamp > NOW() - interval '30 days' 
   AND    t3 timestamp > '2015-06-07 0:0'  -- match index condition
   AND    t3.client_id > 0
   AND    t3.id = t1.id
   );
```

You can use a function as pseudo-constant in partial index and query and automate the process. Last chapter in this related answer:

- [Get latest child per parent from big table - query is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087861/very-slow-postgresql-query/8088075#8088075)

#### [`SET LOCAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set.html)

Like you found yourself, increasing `work_mem` locally for the query helps if the query needs that much RAM. Consider `SET LOCAL`:

- [work_mem in postgresql on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106181/work-mem-in-postgresql-on-linux/8108807#8108807)
- [Speed up creation of Postgres partial index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102509/speed-up-creation-of-postgres-partial-index/102513#102513)

With all suggested improvements in place you may not need to increase `work_mem` any more.

Comment: Is it a typo in the first exists clause (`WHERE  EXISTS (`)?

Comment: @Lennart: thanks, I was missing a `NOT` there. That why I was also missing that your query with LEFT JOINs is very similar to mine.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried rewriting your `NOT IN` predicates as `LEFT JOIN`s?

```
SELECT t1.id || ':' || t1.group_number AS uniq_id
FROM table_one t1
LEFT JOIN table_two t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
   AND t1.group_number = t2.group_number
LEFT JOIN table_three t3
    ON t1.id = t3.id
   AND t3.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'  
   AND t3.client_id > 0
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
  AND t3.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this and it returned the expected results in 24 seconds.  I'll mark you as answering the question, but want to leave it open a while longer to see if there is further discussion on the work_mem / settings issue.  While rewriting the query solves the problem, if it's related to settings I don't want to hide the symptom before diagnosing the underlying problem and making a more permanent fix.

Comment: There may be a performance disadvantage for multiple LEFT JOINs to tables with multiple matches multiplying each other before rows can be eliminated. Compare: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/query-takes-hours/10458#10458. If that's the case, switching to `NOT EXISTS` should be faster.

Comment: If think the situation is slightly different here than in that thread. First the predicates in the where clause are "positive", i.e. they are trying to find something, second the disjunction makes it difficult to filter. This could certainly cause a high cardinality on an intermediate result. In this query it is a lot easier to filter early, and I would expect the optimizer to handle that properly. Still, it is a good idea to check the plans for different solutions and see what performs better. Ideally not only with current statistics, but also with statistics from an expected future.

Comment: @Lennart: Exactly. I didn't run a test case. I was hoping the OP could compare an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for both and report back.

Comment: I've updated my original post with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for each approach. Thanks!

Comment: @Lennart: Given the subsequent detailed answer by Erwin I have to reneg on saying I'd mark your post as answering the question.  Given peoples tendency to only read the marked answer I think it will serve the stack exchange community best to mark that answer.  Thanks for your role in the answer and the back and forth, it was very helpful.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it is the best answer and should be marked as such.