# "Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.4, execution-plan

This is a spin-off from comments to the previous question:

- [Postgres 9.4.4 query takes forever](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106126/postgres-9-4-4-query-takes-forever)

Using PostgreSQL 9.4, there always seems to be a **`Recheck Cond:`** line after bitmap index scans in query plans output by `EXPLAIN`.

Like in the `EXPLAIN` output of the referenced question:

> ```
> ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table_three  (cost=2446.92..19686.74 rows=8159 width=7)
>       Recheck Cond: (("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval)) AND (client_id > 0))
>       ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2446.92..2446.92 rows=8159 width=0)
>             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_one_timestamp_idx  (cost=0.00..1040.00 rows=79941 width=0)
>                   Index Cond: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
>             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fki_table_three_client_id  (cost=0.00..1406.05 rows=107978 width=0)
>                   Index Cond: (client_id > 0)
> ```

Or in the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for a simple, huge table (with very little `work_mem`):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM aa WHERE a BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000;
```

> ```
> Bitmap Heap Scan on aa  (cost=107.68..4818.05 rows=5000 width=4) (actual time=27.629..213.606 rows=100001 loops=1)
>   Recheck Cond: ((a >= 100000) AND (a <= 200000))
>   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 758222
>   Heap Blocks: exact=693 lossy=3732
>   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on aai  (cost=0.00..106.43 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=27.265..27.265 rows=100001 loops=1)
>         Index Cond: ((a >= 100000) AND (a <= 200000))
> ```

Does that mean index conditions have to be checked a second time after a bitmap index scan?
What else can we learn from the `EXPLAIN` output?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As [@Chris commented correctly on the referenced question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106126/postgres-9-4-4-query-takes-forever?noredirect=1#comment193133_106126):

> a little investigation seems to indicate that the recheck condition is
> always printed in the `EXPLAIN`, but is actually only performed when
> `work_mem` is small enough that the bitmap becomes lossy. Thoughts?
> http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/464F3C5D.2000700@enterprisedb.com

While this is all true and the core developer Heikki Linnakangas is a first class source, the post dates back to 2007 (Postgres 8.2). Here is a [blog post by Michael Paquier with detailed explanation for Postgres 9.4](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-lossyexact-pages-for-bitmap-heap-scan/), where the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` has been improved with more information.

The `Recheck Cond:` line is *always* there for bitmap index scans. The output of basic [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) won't tell us more. We get additional information from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` as can be seen in the second quote in the question:

```
Heap Blocks: exact=693 lossy=3732
```

From a total of 4425 data pages (blocks), 693 stored tuples ***exactly*** (including tuple pointers), while the other 3732 pages were ***lossy*** (just the data page) in the bitmap. That happens when `work_mem` is not big enough to store the whole bitmap built from the index scan exactly (lossless).

The index condition has to be rechecked for pages from the lossy share, since the bitmap only remembers which pages to fetch and not the exact tuples on the page. Not all tuples on the page will necessarily pass the index conditions, it's necessary to *actually* recheck the condition.

This is the [thread on pgsql hackers where the new addition was discussed](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CACoZds1nh6YD_X_Kdy7Yx=QVquULTX3nvJbmz9G7uW7Zf9aGMA@mail.gmail.com#CACoZds1nh6YD_X_Kdy7Yx=QVquULTX3nvJbmz9G7uW7Zf9aGMA@mail.gmail.com). The author [Etsuro Fujita provides a formula](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/005401ced6f1$e2005ca0$a60115e0$@lab.ntt.co.jp) for how to calculate the minimum `work_mem` to avoid lossy bitmap entries and ensuing condition rechecks. The calculation is not reliable for complex cases with multiple bitmap scans, so it was not used to output actual numbers from `EXPLAIN`. It can still serve as an estimate for simple cases.

#### Additional line `BUFFERS:`

In addition, when running with `BUFFERS` option: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ...` another line is added like:

```
Buffers: shared hit=279 read=79
```

This indicates how much of the underlying table (and index) was read from the cache (`shared hit=279`) and how much had to be fetched from disk (`read=79`). If you repeat the query, the "read" part typically disappears for not-too-huge queries, because everything is cached now after the first call. The first call tells you how much was cached already. Subsequent calls show how much your cache can handle (currently).

There are more options. [The manual about the `BUFFERS` option:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html#id-1.9.3.148.8)

> Specifically, include the number of shared blocks hit, read,
> dirtied, and written, the number of local blocks hit, read, dirtied,
> and written, and the number of temp blocks read and written.

Read on, there's more.
Here is the list of output options in the [source code](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/instrument_8h_source.html#l00021).

Answer (score 12):

Erwin, since this was our discussion in the comment thread from before, I decided to poke at it a little further...

I have a very simple query from a reasonably sized table.  I typically have sufficient `work_mem`, but in this case I used the commands

```
SET work_mem = 64;
```

to set a very small `work_mem` and

```
SET work_mem = default;
```

to set my `work_mem` back to being sufficiently large for my query.

## EXPLAIN & Recheck Condition

So, running my query with only `EXPLAIN` as

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM olap.reading_facts
WHERE meter < 20;
```

I obtained the results for both low & high `work_mem`:

**Low `work_mem`**

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on reading_facts  (cost=898.92..85632.60 rows=47804 width=32)
  Recheck Cond: (meter < 20)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_meter_reading_facts  (cost=0.00..886.96 rows=47804 width=0)
        Index Cond: (meter < 20)
```

**High `work_mem`**

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on reading_facts  (cost=898.92..85632.60 rows=47804 width=32)
  Recheck Cond: (meter < 20)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_meter_reading_facts  (cost=0.00..886.96 rows=47804 width=0)
        Index Cond: (meter < 20)
```

Long story short, for `EXPLAIN` only, as expected the query plan indicates that a Recheck condition is possible, but we can't know if will actually be computed.

## EXPLAIN ANALYZE & Recheck Condition

When we include `ANALYZE` in the query, the results tel us more about what we need to know.

**Low `work_mem`**

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on reading_facts  (cost=898.92..85632.60 rows=47804 width=32) (actual time=3.130..13.946 rows=51840 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (meter < 20)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 86727
  Heap Blocks: exact=598 lossy=836
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_meter_reading_facts  (cost=0.00..886.96 rows=47804 width=0) (actual time=3.066..3.066 rows=51840 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (meter < 20)
```

**High `work_mem`**

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on reading_facts  (cost=898.92..85632.60 rows=47804 width=32) (actual time=2.647..7.247 rows=51840 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (meter < 20)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1434
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_meter_reading_facts  (cost=0.00..886.96 rows=47804 width=0) (actual time=2.496..2.496 rows=51840 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (meter < 20)
```

Again, as expected, the inclusion of `ANALYZE` reveals to us some very important information.  In the low `work_mem` case, we see that there are rows removed by the index recheck, and that we have `lossy` heap blocks.

## Conclusion? (or lack thereof)

Unfortunately, it looks like `EXPLAIN` on its own is ***not sufficient*** to know whether an index recheck will actually be necessary because some of the row id's are being dropped in favor of retaining pages during the bitmap heap scan.

Using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is fine for diagnosing the issues with moderate length queries, but in the case that a query is taking an extremely long time to complete, then running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to discover that your bitmap index is converting to lossy due to insufficient `work_mem` is still a difficult constraint.  I wish there was a way to have `EXPLAIN` estimate the likelihood of this occurrence from the table statistics.