# Queries using GIN index on f_unaccent() seem slow?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, gist-index, gin-index, postgresql-performance

I have almost 20M rows in one table that contains product, including their names.

I wish to search fulltext and fast by the name so I created this index:

```
CREATE INDEX uprice_item_occurrence_unaccent_name_trgm_idx ON price_item_occurrence USING gin (f_unaccent(name) gin_trgm_ops);;
```

I was hopping the following query would take less then (lets say) 500ms

```
select * from price_item_occurrence as oo
where f_unaccent(oo.name) % f_unaccent('iphone');
```

But it takes almost 2s:

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from price_item_occurrence as oo where f_unaccent(oo.name) % f_unaccent('iphone');
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on price_item_occurrence oo  (cost=1956.42..63674.14 rows=16570 width=287) (actual time=247.918..1880.759 rows=94 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (f_unaccent((name)::text) % 'iphone'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 87838
   Heap Blocks: exact=76663
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uprice_item_occurrence_unaccent_name_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..1952.28 rows=16570 width=0) (actual time=195.418..195.418 rows=88962 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (f_unaccent((name)::text) % 'iphone'::text)
 Planning time: 0.444 ms
 Execution time: 1880.833 ms
```

It's possible that the DB is busy, but i am not sure.

I tried to play with `select set_limit(0.9);` (increased) and it helps a bit but not much.

I am using Postgres 10, can change the Postgres config and I am open for suggestions.

I tried it with `ilike` and it improved by some:

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from price_item_occurrence as oo where f_unaccent(oo.name) ilike ('%' || f_unaccent('iphone') || '%');
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on price_item_occurrence oo  (cost=3135.08..416823.45 rows=166075 width=286) (actual time=50.258..670.085 rows=65917 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (f_unaccent((name)::text) ~~* '%iphone%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 10
   Heap Blocks: exact=59750
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uprice_item_occurrence_unaccent_name_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..3093.56 rows=166075 width=0) (actual time=37.385..37.385 rows=67700 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (f_unaccent((name)::text) ~~* '%iphone%'::text)
 Planning time: 0.545 ms
 Execution time: 675.776 ms
(8 rows)
```

About 2x faster.

i tried `limit 10`:

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from price_item_occurrence as oo where f_unaccent(oo.name) % f_unaccent('iphone') limit 10;
                                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=373.27..410.51 rows=10 width=287) (actual time=268.718..589.131 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on price_item_occurrence oo  (cost=373.27..62493.45 rows=16680 width=287) (actual time=268.715..589.123 rows=10 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (f_unaccent((name)::text) % 'iphone'::text)
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 18917
         Heap Blocks: exact=17100
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uprice_item_occurrence_unaccent_name_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..369.10 rows=16680 width=0) (actual time=165.958..165.958 rows=69268 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (f_unaccent((name)::text) % 'iphone'::text)
 Planning time: 0.397 ms
 Execution time: 589.187 ms
(9 rows)
```

this is also faster, maybe almost good enough

Comment: Your index definiton says `(name gist_trgm_ops)`. I assume that's a typo and it's actually on `(f_unaccent(name) gist_trgm_ops)`? And please explain more closely what you want to find *exactly*. The similarity operator `%` and `ILIKE` vastly differ. Also: your *exact* definition of `f_unaccent()`. Did you base it on this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860

Comment: `(name gist_trgm_ops)` is not a typo but maybe its incorrect, the index is still used in the query. I want to find products (names) that contain the 'iphone' text (its just an example). I know that `ILIKE` and `%` are different but i can imagine to use both.

Comment: Please don't change the nature of the question after answers have been posted. Switching to GIN makes it a different question. You can always start a new question - with consistent information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen **GIN** indexes to generally perform much faster than GiST for these queries. Try this index instead:

```
CREATE INDEX price_item_occurrence_name_trgm_gin idx ON price_item_occurrence
USING GIN (f_unaccent(name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Related:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)
- [Using ILIKE with unaccent and with only right end wildcard](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129202/using-ilike-with-unaccent-and-with-only-right-end-wildcard/129215#129215)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)
- [Trigram index for ILIKE patterns not working as expected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138288/trigram-index-for-for-ilike-patterns-not-working-as-expected/138526#138526)

All the basic advice for performance optimization applies. For starters, your table needs to be `VACUUM`ed and `ANALYZE`d enough to be fast.

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: kk thx i try and let you know

Comment: Ok so to my shame i realised that i already had a gin index same as you suggested, and its already used in the example above `uprice_item_occurrence_unaccent_name_trgm_idx`
sorry for misleading information, i update the question.