# Poor SELECT performance on recheck cond with data and large (millions of rows) partial index

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization

Query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT
    COUNT (*) AS "count"
FROM
    "Posts" AS "Post"
WHERE
    "Post"."createdAt" > '2015-08-19 14:55:50.398'
AND "Post"."new" = TRUE;
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_new_createdat_idx ON "Posts" ("createdAt")
WHERE
    NEW = TRUE
```

Plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=389915.59..389915.60 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=4234.772..4234.773 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=254427
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Posts" "Post"  (cost=14415.81..387990.63 rows=769985 width=0) (actual time=123.805..3859.150 rows=1138854 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (("createdAt" > '2015-08-19 14:55:50.398+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND new)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 8238790
        Buffers: shared hit=254427
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on posts_new_createdat_idx  (cost=0.00..14223.32 rows=769985 width=0) (actual time=122.601..122.601 rows=1138854 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ("createdAt" > '2015-08-19 14:55:50.398+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              Buffers: shared hit=3114
Total runtime: 4234.989 ms
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."Posts" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Posts_id_seq"'::regclass),
    "actionId" int4,
    "commentCount" int4 DEFAULT 0,
    "facebook" bool,
    "featurePostOnDate" timestamp(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
    "forcedPrivate" bool,
    "instagram" bool,
    "isReported" bool,
    "likeCount" int4 DEFAULT 0,
    "note" text COLLATE "default",
    "photo" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "private" bool,
    "new" bool,
    "popular" bool,
    "twitter" bool,
    "userId" int4,
    "objectId" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "createdAt" timestamp(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
    "updatedAt" timestamp(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
    "activityLogId" int4,
    "weightLogId" int4,
    "workoutId" int4,
    "workoutLogId" int4,
    "thumbnail" varchar(255) COLLATE "default"
)
```

Data:

- `new = true` for 99% or records
- Any posts older than 2 weeks can be ignored (from the count and the index)

Database Details:

```
Host           = Amazon AWS
Engine         = PostgreSQL 9.3.10
Instance Class = db.r3.8xlarge
Storage Type   = SSD
IOPS           = 3000
StorageAmount  = 500 GB
```

As you can see, the partial index is very large. Is there a way to better index so that the recheck condition is not so heavy?

Comment: You forgot to provide your version of Postgres, the table definition and some explanation for the query. Is the timestamp a constant or a moving target? Moving how? And what is the data distribution in the table?

Comment: Noted; I've added **Schema**, **Data** and **Database Details**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the second predicate of your query to the partial index as well:

```
WHERE "Post"."createdAt" > '2015-08-19 14:55:50.398'
```

Your timestamp is probably a moving target, but I am going to assume you have lots of old rows that are excluded in most of your queries and only few "younger" rows are of interest. A typical use case. You can cut off old rows in your partial index.

```
CREATE INDEX posts_new_createdat_idx ON "Posts"("createdAt")
WHERE "new"
AND   "createdAt" > '2015-08-01 00:00';  -- replace with useful timestamp
```

This only makes sense if you can reduce the size of the index to a fraction. Else, the effect is typically not worth the trouble.

Replace with an opportune timestamp to cut off as many rows as possible while still covering relevant rows for your queries.

Modern versions of Postgres are smart enough to understand the index is applicable to queries cutting off at a later timestamp. For older versions you have to add the verbatim index condition redundantly to make the query planner use this partial index.

This index will be used by your query immediately *as is*. (I just removed some more noise):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM  "Posts"
WHERE "createdAt" > '2015-08-19 14:55:50.398'
AND   "new";
```

Related:

- [Add datetime constraint to a PostgreSQL multi-column partial index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14746476/939860)
- ["Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan)

Aside 1: `"new" = TRUE` is just a noisy way of stating `"new"` for a boolean value.

Aside 2: Don't use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) or CaMeL case or other illegal identifiers so you don't have to double-quote all the time. Very error prone.

Comment: Interesting. This would only scale, then, if the date is a variable timestamp (say 2 weeks ago), which I'm guessing is not supported.

Comment: @Garrett: The query can operate with a variable timestamp, no problem. As long as it logically fits with the partial index, it can be used. But the index condition requires a constant. Instructions how to adapt the index over time at the link I provided above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14746476/939860

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for a recheck to happen in this particular query is that the bitmap is too large to fit in work_mem and so has to be down-graded to lossy.  So to avoid the recheck, try to increase `work_mem`, if you can afford to.  You shouldn't have to increase it by much to hold 1138854 tuples.

Newer versions of PostgreSQL make this clearer, by including lines like this in the "EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)":

```
Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 33
Heap Blocks: exact=558 lossy=15682
```

However, don't expect anything magic here once you get rid of the recheck. You might be overestimating the amount of time spend on the recheck, versus other things.