# Is it possible to get a "pages touched" statistic from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, index, data-pages, page-splits

With PostgreSQL one can measure disk reads and cache hits. Is it possible to have a clearer statistic of how many index pages were "touched" to run a query? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze your query with [**`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) (`BUFFERS` being the essential option to see details about memory utilization). A "buffer" in RAM is the equivalent of a "block" on disk, 8 kb on most installations.

Example:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) 
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl_id = 123;
```

With a big table `tbl` that's not cached, yet (not recently queried), and a btree index on `tbl_id`, you'll see something like:

> ```
> Index Scan using tbl_pkey on tbl  (cost=0.43..5.45 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=61.360..61.363 rows=1 loops=1)
>   Index Cond: (tbl_id = 12345)
>   Buffers: shared read=4
> ```

Meaning that 4 data pages have been read from disk. That includes both index *and* table pages. For an index scan reading a single row from a big table, that's typically 3 blocks from the index and one from the table.
(For a small table you'd see `shared read=2` - only 1 index page for a shallow btree index.)

If you repeat the same, you typically see the same, executed much faster and one difference:

> ```
>   Buffers: shared hit=4
> ```

Meaning that 4 data pages have been read ***from cache***, cached due to the first invocation.

[The manual explains:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html#AEN87641)

> `BUFFERS`
>
> Include information on buffer usage. Specifically, include the number
>   of shared blocks hit, read, dirtied, and written, the number of local
>   blocks hit, read, dirtied, and written, and the number of temp blocks
>   read and written. A **hit** means that a read was avoided because the
>   block was found already in cache when needed. Shared blocks contain
>   data from regular tables and indexes; local blocks contain data from
>   temporary tables and indexes; while temp blocks contain short-term
>   working data used in sorts, hashes, Materialize plan nodes, and
>   similar cases. The number of blocks **dirtied** indicates the number of
>   previously unmodified blocks that were changed by this query; while
>   the number of blocks **written** indicates the number of
>   previously-dirtied blocks evicted from cache by this backend during
>   query processing. The number of blocks shown for an upper-level node
>   includes those used by all its child nodes. In text format, only
>   non-zero values are printed. This parameter may only be used when
>   `ANALYZE` is also enabled. It defaults to `FALSE`.

Related:

- ["Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan/106267#106267)

Comment: Thanks!! But isn't EXPLAIN a guess i.e. isn't there a possibility that when the actual execution happens, the real result is different? If this is so, how can I measure the 'actual' reads and hits?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is based on the execution *plan*. `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` actually executes the SELECT, and gives an answer based on the *real execution*. See [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)

Comment: When I run a query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE, (planning time+ execution time) is smaller than total query runtime. Where does this difference come from?

Comment: @audlift-bit; Define "total execution time". For one, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` incurs some overhead for timing, obviously.  `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` even a bit more. On the other hand, there is also the time for data transfer / network latency (which can easily be the lion's share, depending on your connection and query) and time your client uses to process and display results. You need to look closely what you measure exactly. Measurements you get from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` only reflect the share of the RDBMS, not network or client.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm not referring to "total execution time" but to "total query runtime" which is time taken from issuing of command to spitting the result on screen. This is much smaller than what `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns and I would like to know why. Yes, I can understand connection making a difference but I am on a local cluster.

Comment: @audlift-bit: Sorry for the mismatch in terms. The question stands: what are you measuring exactly? Your description `time taken from issuing of command to spitting the result on screen` is not the *total query time* but, in fact, a *total execution time*. Also, your comments seem to contradict each other. 1: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE is smaller than total query runtime` 2: `is much smaller than what EXPLAIN ANALYZE returns`, which is the opposite. Either way, none of this directly relates to the *question*. I suggest you start a new question with clear details. Comments are not the place.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Apologies on the contradiction. I mixed up. The first is what confused me a bit and what I'm standing by: the totals of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` are less than the runtime (returned by the PgAdmin GUI). I would appreciate any help on this. I suppose I will open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @audlift-bit: as said before the "total execution time" reported by your SQL client includes the time to transfer the data over the network. The time reported by `explain (analyze)` reports the time it took to run the query on the server _without_ sending data to the client

Comment: Regarding local blocks, could you please provide some more explanation as I still do not fully understand it. If my plan would use an index, it can still have 0 local hit/read blocks so what's going on?

Comment: Also since we can see buffers used in subplans, do I have to add them up to get the total blocks used, or is the topmost plan displaying the overall used?