# How can I speed up my query that involves `max(timestamp)` in a huge table? I already added an index to every field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, greatest-n-per-group, slow-query

I have a huge table that has fields `ip`, `mac`, and `timestamp`.

Neither of the three fields is unique, but the combination of all three is.

Table is automatically populated, with newer records added all the time. The field `timestamp` refers to when a row was added. Records are never *UPDATE*d.

Here's the table description:

```
  Column   |            Type             | Nullable | Default
-----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------
 event     | text                        | not null |
 ip        | inet                        | not null |
 mac       | macaddr8                    | not null |
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "ip_idx" btree (ip)
    "mac_idx" btree (mac)
    "time_idx" btree ("timestamp")
    "timestamp_ip_event_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("timestamp", ip, event)
```

I have this very slow query, causing the website to take very long time to load

How can I speed it up?

Is it possible to take advantage of the fact that the table is basically ordered by timestamp?

I do not have access to the script that adds records.

```
Executed SQL
select ip,
       max(timestamp)
  from my_table
 WHERE ip << inet '10.38.69.0/24'
 group by ip
 order by ip;
Time
2151.577594000173 ms
Database
default
QUERY PLAN
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=291919.94..292190.52 rows=1068 width=15) (actual time=696.246..704.698 rows=151 loops=1)
  Group Key: ip
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=291919.94..292169.16 rows=2136 width=15) (actual time=696.220..704.558 rows=429 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=290919.92..290922.59 rows=1068 width=15) (actual time=679.313..679.325 rows=143 loops=3)
              Sort Key: ip
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=290855.52..290866.20 rows=1068 width=15) (actual time=679.192..679.233 rows=143 loops=3)
                    Group Key: ip
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 81kB
                    Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 81kB
                    Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 81kB
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table  (cost=12023.68..289019.89 rows=367126 width=15) (actual time=67.898..580.432 rows=312819 loops=3)
                          Filter: (ip << '10.38.69.0/24'::inet)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1716854
                          Heap Blocks: exact=15528 lossy=18121
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_table_ip_idx  (cost=0.00..11803.41 rows=881097 width=0) (actual time=62.721..62.721 rows=938457 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((ip > '10.38.69.0/24'::inet) AND (ip <= '10.38.69.255'::inet))
Planning Time: 1.049 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 30
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.180 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.470 ms, Emission 29.303 ms, Total 32.952 ms
Execution Time: 726.126 ms
```

Comment: If the combination of all 3 columns is unique doesn't that mean you have to create a unique index for these 3 columns instead of 1 for each?

Comment: I would imagine a single index on both ip and timestamp would do the trick.

Comment: Your execution time is reported in 3 different places, and they differ from each other by a factor of 3.  It isn't clear where that first (slowest) time is coming from.  Is that the time reported by the `psql` \timing option?

Comment: turn on track_io_timing, then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to get more valuable info included in the plan.  Also, is it faster the 2nd time you run the exact same query back to back?

Comment: @BillerBuilder yes, there is a btree unique index over three columns. I added table description

Comment: @GrannyAching: But the added unique constraint is on `("timestamp", ip, event)`, *not*  `(ip, mac, timestamp)`. Please present a coherent question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Not enough `work_mem`

The lion share of the cost is accrued here:

```
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table  (cost=12023.68..289019.89 rows=367126 width=15) (actual time=67.898..580.432 rows=312819 loops=3)
                          Filter: (ip << '10.38.69.0/24'::inet)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1716854
                          Heap Blocks: exact=15528 lossy=18121
```

Note **`lossy=18121`**, meaning there was not enough `work_mem` to store tuple pointers of matching index entries. Postgres only remembers data pages. Consequently, all tuples of those "lossy" pages have to be rechecked, and most of them filtered out: `Rows Removed by Filter: 1716854`, which is expensive.

Increase your **`work_mem`** setting - if you can afford that. Maybe just for your session or just this query if it's exceptionally expensive. Increase to an amount where you get no more "lossy" pages. See:

- ["Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan/106267#106267)

#### Better query

That said, you probably won't need additional `work_mem` with this **much more efficient query** emulating an index skip scan:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT ip, timestamp
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  ip << inet '10.38.69.0/24'
   ORDER  BY ip, timestamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT t.*
      FROM   my_table t
      WHERE  t.ip > c.ip
      AND    ip << inet '10.38.69.0/24'
      ORDER  BY ip, timestamp DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) t
   )
TABLE  cte;
```

While the query also works with the index on just `(ip)`, it isn't typically much faster than your original. You need this matching multicolumn index to make it ***fast***:

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_ip_time_stamp_idx ON my_table(ip, timestamp DESC);
```

See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894500/939860)

Remarkably similar question & answer from just today:

- [PostgreSQL fast query to get most recent rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76879521/939860)

Comment: But it says "removed by filter", not "removed by recheck".  This is do to the fact that IP addresses are not simple scalars, not due to lack of work_mem.

Comment: @jjanes: But  while it's true that a lossy GiST index *also* needs a recheck, I don't think this is what we see here. I reproduced the above case in current Postgres 15 and for plenty `work_mem` I get: `->  Bitmap Heap Scan ... Filter: ... Heap Blocks: exact=...`, while for insufficient `work_mem` I get: `->  Bitmap Heap Scan ... Filter: ... Rows Removed by Filter: ... Heap Blocks: exact=... lossy=...` Notably, `lossy` only pops up for lacking mem, and only then do I see `Rows Removed by Filter:`. Can this be the rare case where you are wrong in this area?

Comment: With a plain B-tree index on `(ip)` btw, like the OP declared.

Comment: So the filter subsumes the recheck. It doesn't bother to do the recheck since the filter would already catch these failures , but that means the reported 'removed' count mingles two reasons together.  So yes it could be work_mem is too low; raising it should help with a CPU bottleneck, but not an IO bottleneck.

Comment: Odd that nothing is reported "removed" when the heap blocks don't go lossy.