# Postgres 4x Slower Than It Was

Tags: performance, postgresql-9.4, database-tuning, performance-tuning, postgresql-performance

Our Postgres performance has gone down to 1/4 of what it was, and we can't figure out why.

We have two machines with identical hardware (let's call them A and B):

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4640 0 @ 2.40GHz (64 cores)
384 GB RAM
15k SAS, 16 disk RAID 10 array
```

Each machine has essentially identical Postgres clusters with about 100 GB databases, with the following settings:

```
version:   PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11), 64-bit
bytea_output:   escape
checkpoint_completion_target:   0.7
checkpoint_segments:   256
checkpoint_timeout:   30min
client_encoding:   UTF8
cpu_index_tuple_cost:   0.001
cpu_operator_cost:   0.0005
cpu_tuple_cost:   0.003
DateStyle:   ISO, MDY
default_text_search_config:   pg_catalog.english
dynamic_shared_memory_type:   posix
effective_cache_size:   128GB
from_collapse_limit:   4
hot_standby:   on
join_collapse_limit:   4
lc_messages:   en_US.UTF-8
lc_monetary:   en_US.UTF-8
lc_numeric:   en_US.UTF-8
lc_time:   en_US.UTF-8
listen_addresses:   *
log_destination:   stderr
log_directory:   pg_log
log_filename:   postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
log_line_prefix:   < %m >
log_rotation_age:   1d
log_rotation_size:   0
log_timezone:   US/Eastern
log_truncate_on_rotation:   on
logging_collector:   on
maintenance_work_mem:   1GB
max_connections:   256
max_replication_slots:   3
max_stack_depth:   2MB
max_standby_streaming_delay:   350min
max_wal_senders:   5
shared_buffers:   24GB
temp_buffers:   8MB
TimeZone:   US/Eastern
wal_buffers:   4MB
wal_keep_segments:   5000
wal_level:   hot_standby
work_mem:   96MB
```

Linux settings:

```
CentOS 6.6
/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled:   Always
/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled:   Always
/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/defrag:   Always
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio:   10
/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler:   cfq
/sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb:   128

blockdev --report:
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0   2395518009344   /dev/sda
rw   256   512  4096       2048      1048576000   /dev/sda1
rw   256   512  4096    2050048   1792509214720   /dev/sda2
rw   256   512  4096 3503044608    314572800000   /dev/sda3
rw   256   512  4096 4117444608    149946368000   /dev/sda4
rw   256   512  4096 4410308608    137438953472   /dev/sda5
```

I don't claim to understand all that.

We have streaming replication that keeps a hot copy of A on B. That puts B under heavier load, especially in the memory department, and it goes into swap (so clearly we're doing something wrong, since we have 384 GB of RAM).

```
free -g (on A):
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           378        347         30         24          2        301
-/+ buffers/cache:         44        334
Swap:          127          1        126

free -g (on B):
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           378        366         11         49          2        340
-/+ buffers/cache:         23        354
Swap:          127          1        126
```

The load is usually 5 or 10, but at times will go to 30 - 60 for a few hours when intensive reporting or database operations are done.

Backing up the entire database used to take ~1 hour, now it takes ~4.

Syncing the database on A to B (B is used for development and we refresh the live data to from A to B) used to take ~1 hour, now it takes ~4.

Queries that used to take 30 seconds (for years) started hanging for days without returning (increasing the work_mem for that query solved that problem: [Postgres 9.4.4 query takes forever](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106126/postgres-9-4-4-query-takes-forever)).

We have Tomcat websites and processes that run, using C3P0 for pooling, and Apache / PHP sites and processes that run, using pgBouncer for pooling.  We've considered having Tomcat use pgBouncer as well.

We've considered trying to lower our max connections from 256 to 64 (256 is from before we were using connection pooling).

Our current settings come from a combination of pgtune and research, but my confidence in our current configuration isn't high, and our the performance drop doesn't help that confidence.

Any recommendations?  Any additional info needed?

**Update**

Output of iostat:

```
Server A
Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 (openlink1.radyn.com)  08/05/2015  _x86_64_    (64 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          27.09    0.03    1.15    0.06    0.00   71.67

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda             258.93      2136.65     20871.52 4370455736 42692153072

Server B
Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 (openlink2.radyn.com)  08/05/2015  _x86_64_    (64 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          26.90    0.00    1.58    0.17    0.00   71.35

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda             459.18     12641.47     17765.60 28973539688 40717751832
```

Output of vmstat:

```
Server A
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 7  0 1297844 8265380 2688960 333189664    0    0    17   163    0    0 27  1 72  0  0

Server B
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 9  0 3321548 16228276 2221908 349418368    0    0    99   139    0    0 27  2 71  0  0
```

Output of sar:

```
Server A
Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 (openlink1.radyn.com)  08/05/2015  _x86_64_    (64 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all     13.25      0.00      1.05      0.04      0.00     85.66
12:20:01 AM     all     11.98      0.00      0.53      0.03      0.00     87.46
12:30:01 AM     all     11.86      0.00      0.67      0.03      0.00     87.43
12:40:01 AM     all     12.33      0.00      0.94      0.04      0.00     86.68
12:50:01 AM     all     11.39      0.00      0.52      0.06      0.00     88.03
01:00:01 AM     all     13.58      0.00      1.28      0.03      0.00     85.11
01:10:01 AM     all     13.37      0.00      0.82      0.02      0.00     85.79
01:20:01 AM     all     11.74      0.00      0.54      0.01      0.00     87.70
01:30:01 AM     all     12.00      0.00      0.70      0.02      0.00     87.28
01:40:01 AM     all     13.10      0.00      0.80      0.02      0.00     86.08
01:50:01 AM     all     13.19      0.00      1.06      0.02      0.00     85.73
02:00:02 AM     all     15.62      0.00      1.55      0.03      0.00     82.80
02:10:01 AM     all     18.72      0.00      2.98      0.03      0.00     78.27
02:20:02 AM     all     15.95      0.12      2.33      0.05      0.00     81.55
02:30:01 AM     all     13.58      0.01      0.89      0.01      0.00     85.51
02:40:01 AM     all     19.23      0.00      1.91      0.05      0.00     78.80
02:50:02 AM     all     23.95      0.00      0.92      0.05      0.00     75.08
03:00:01 AM     all     13.69      0.00      0.59      0.01      0.00     85.72
03:10:01 AM     all     12.87      0.00      0.49      0.01      0.00     86.64
03:20:01 AM     all     12.18      0.00      0.69      0.02      0.00     87.11
03:30:01 AM     all     11.82      0.74      0.70      0.05      0.00     86.69
03:40:01 AM     all     62.02      0.00      2.18      0.01      0.00     35.79
03:50:01 AM     all     72.96      0.00      0.71      0.00      0.00     26.32
04:00:01 AM     all     71.97      0.00      0.72      0.00      0.00     27.30
04:10:01 AM     all     71.71      0.00      0.71      0.00      0.00     27.57
04:20:01 AM     all     72.40      0.00      0.80      0.01      0.00     26.80
04:30:01 AM     all     68.69      0.00      1.24      0.00      0.00     30.07
04:40:01 AM     all     68.68      0.00      1.12      0.02      0.00     30.18
04:50:01 AM     all     72.59      0.00      0.79      0.00      0.00     26.62
05:00:01 AM     all     72.09      0.00      0.81      0.00      0.00     27.10
05:10:01 AM     all     72.61      0.00      0.79      0.00      0.00     26.59
05:20:01 AM     all     72.19      0.00      0.83      0.00      0.00     26.98
05:30:01 AM     all     75.98      0.00      1.14      0.00      0.00     22.87
05:40:02 AM     all     73.85      0.00      1.19      0.00      0.00     24.96
05:50:02 AM     all     73.47      0.00      1.21      0.00      0.00     25.32
06:00:01 AM     all     75.27      0.00      1.24      0.00      0.00     23.49
06:10:01 AM     all     76.56      0.00      1.18      0.00      0.00     22.25
06:20:01 AM     all     77.06      0.20      1.24      0.00      0.00     21.50
06:30:01 AM     all     76.44      0.00      1.29      0.00      0.00     22.27
06:40:01 AM     all     77.16      0.00      1.44      0.00      0.00     21.39
06:50:01 AM     all     76.88      0.00      1.18      0.00      0.00     21.94
07:00:01 AM     all     76.28      0.00      1.12      0.00      0.00     22.60
07:10:01 AM     all     49.72      0.00      1.49      0.11      0.00     48.67
07:20:01 AM     all     12.78      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00     86.21
07:30:01 AM     all     14.26      0.00      1.04      0.00      0.00     84.70
07:40:01 AM     all     15.19      0.00      1.11      0.00      0.00     83.70
07:50:01 AM     all     12.85      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00     86.17
08:00:01 AM     all     14.24      0.00      0.94      0.00      0.00     84.82
08:10:01 AM     all     13.09      0.00      0.98      0.00      0.00     85.93
08:20:01 AM     all     13.16      0.00      0.88      0.00      0.00     85.96
08:30:01 AM     all      9.87      0.00      0.53      0.00      0.00     89.60
08:40:01 AM     all      8.41      0.00      0.66      0.00      0.00     90.92
08:50:01 AM     all     10.09      0.00      0.75      0.00      0.00     89.16
09:00:01 AM     all      7.66      0.00      0.52      0.00      0.00     91.82
09:10:01 AM     all      6.68      0.00      0.43      0.00      0.00     92.89

09:10:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:20:01 AM     all      7.20      0.00      0.41      0.00      0.00     92.39
09:30:01 AM     all      6.74      0.00      0.44      0.00      0.00     92.82
09:40:01 AM     all      6.70      0.00      0.43      0.00      0.00     92.87
09:50:01 AM     all      8.12      0.00      0.54      0.04      0.00     91.30
10:00:01 AM     all     10.44      0.00      0.60      0.02      0.00     88.93
10:10:01 AM     all     10.86      0.00      0.60      0.01      0.00     88.53
10:20:01 AM     all     14.46      0.00      0.77      0.06      0.00     84.72
10:30:01 AM     all      9.31      0.13      0.84      0.10      0.00     89.63
10:40:02 AM     all     10.45      0.00      0.81      0.11      0.00     88.63
Average:        all     32.89      0.02      0.96      0.02      0.00     66.11

Server B
Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 (openlink2.radyn.com)  08/05/2015  _x86_64_    (64 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all     12.29      0.00      2.65      0.30      0.00     84.76
12:20:01 AM     all     16.31      0.00      1.38      0.15      0.00     82.16
12:30:01 AM     all     13.46      0.00      1.59      0.07      0.00     84.88
12:40:01 AM     all     13.05      0.00      1.16      0.17      0.00     85.61
12:50:01 AM     all     11.72      0.00      1.39      0.11      0.00     86.79
01:00:01 AM     all     11.96      0.00      1.77      0.06      0.00     86.21
01:10:01 AM     all     13.21      0.00      1.69      0.06      0.00     85.04
01:20:01 AM     all     13.19      0.00      2.14      0.05      0.00     84.62
01:30:03 AM     all     19.11      0.00      4.31      0.06      0.00     76.52
01:40:02 AM     all      9.29      0.00      4.75      0.04      0.00     85.91
01:50:02 AM     all      7.16      0.00      4.81      0.04      0.00     87.99
02:00:03 AM     all      6.56      0.00      5.26      0.06      0.00     88.12
02:10:02 AM     all      8.05      0.00      7.09      0.06      0.00     84.80
02:20:03 AM     all      8.54      0.00      7.75      0.08      0.00     83.62
02:30:03 AM     all      2.99      0.00      6.20      0.09      0.00     90.72
02:40:03 AM     all     10.79      0.00      7.79      0.21      0.00     81.21
02:50:03 AM     all      5.88      0.00      4.97      0.16      0.00     88.99
03:00:02 AM     all     14.17      0.00      4.99      0.47      0.00     80.37
03:10:01 AM     all     17.17      0.00      4.18      0.26      0.00     78.40
03:20:01 AM     all     29.50      0.00      3.36      0.11      0.00     67.03
03:30:01 AM     all     25.16      0.00      3.05      0.15      0.00     71.64
03:40:01 AM     all     19.70      0.00      2.29      0.15      0.00     77.86
03:50:01 AM     all     28.69      0.00      3.01      0.09      0.00     68.21
04:00:01 AM     all     17.61      0.00      2.73      0.08      0.00     79.58
04:10:01 AM     all     16.72      0.00      2.95      0.09      0.00     80.25
04:20:01 AM     all     13.50      0.00      2.47      0.05      0.00     83.98
04:30:03 AM     all     14.88      0.00      5.20      0.08      0.00     79.84
04:40:02 AM     all     12.05      0.01      6.05      0.10      0.00     81.79
04:50:01 AM     all      9.92      0.00      6.89      0.03      0.00     83.16
05:00:03 AM     all      5.89      0.00      6.89      0.02      0.00     87.20
05:10:02 AM     all      5.22      0.00      5.55      0.05      0.00     89.18
05:20:02 AM     all      6.02      0.00      5.01      0.04      0.00     88.94
05:30:03 AM     all      8.11      0.00      6.05      0.02      0.00     85.82
05:40:02 AM     all     13.53      0.00      3.94      0.01      0.00     82.52
05:50:01 AM     all     18.90      0.00      2.48      0.02      0.00     78.60
06:00:01 AM     all     19.09      0.00      1.64      0.01      0.00     79.26
06:10:01 AM     all     18.63      0.00      1.84      0.06      0.00     79.47
06:20:01 AM     all     19.13      0.00      1.72      0.05      0.00     79.11
06:30:01 AM     all     17.73      0.00      1.94      0.02      0.00     80.31
06:40:01 AM     all     17.97      0.00      1.58      0.02      0.00     80.42
06:50:02 AM     all     12.25      0.00      2.00      0.02      0.00     85.72
07:00:01 AM     all     10.04      0.00      1.31      0.00      0.00     88.64
07:10:01 AM     all     13.39      0.00      1.59      0.00      0.00     85.02
07:20:01 AM     all     14.84      0.00      1.49      0.00      0.00     83.67
07:30:01 AM     all     12.36      0.00      0.80      0.01      0.00     86.84
07:40:01 AM     all     12.07      0.00      0.71      0.01      0.00     87.21
07:50:01 AM     all     12.98      0.00      1.14      0.00      0.00     85.88
08:00:01 AM     all     12.62      0.00      0.93      0.00      0.00     86.44
08:10:01 AM     all     11.77      0.00      0.87      0.00      0.00     87.36
08:20:01 AM     all     11.79      0.00      1.61      0.00      0.00     86.60
08:30:01 AM     all     10.80      0.00      0.79      0.00      0.00     88.40
08:40:02 AM     all     13.49      0.00      1.78      0.00      0.00     84.72
08:50:01 AM     all     12.46      0.00      1.39      0.00      0.00     86.15
09:00:02 AM     all     12.28      0.00      0.83      0.00      0.00     86.89
09:10:01 AM     all     12.65      0.00      0.77      0.01      0.00     86.57

09:10:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:20:01 AM     all     12.44      0.00      0.78      0.00      0.00     86.78
09:30:01 AM     all     12.96      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00     86.03
09:40:01 AM     all     11.71      0.00      0.80      0.00      0.00     87.49
09:50:01 AM     all     15.23      0.00      2.04      0.06      0.00     82.67
10:00:01 AM     all     14.60      0.00      1.66      0.02      0.00     83.72
10:10:01 AM     all     13.97      0.00      2.76      0.01      0.00     83.26
10:20:01 AM     all     15.34      0.00      1.51      0.01      0.00     83.14
10:30:01 AM     all     12.84      0.00      1.34      0.80      0.00     85.03
10:40:01 AM     all     12.96      0.00      1.43      0.81      0.00     84.80
10:50:01 AM     all     14.48      0.00      1.47      0.85      0.00     83.20
Average:        all     13.46      0.00      2.85      0.10      0.00     83.59
```

Comment: if you didn't change anything I would look at the hardware, drive failure, ram issues

Comment: You mentioned you ran this server for years. Have you checked the battery on your raid card? Also, what's the output of iostat, vmstat, and sar during the times in question. Has your workload changed too?

Comment: The raid card batteries both show OK (from Dell iDrac).  I updated the post with iostat, vmstat, and sar.  The workload has slowly increased, but nowhere near enough to account for the slowdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your configurations and output, the only suggestions I can make for you to try are the following.

1. Disable Transparent Huge Pages. Evidence from the [PostgreSQL mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CANQNgOrD02f8mR3Y8Pi=zFsoL14RqNQA8hwz1r4rSnDLr1b2Cw@mail.gmail.com), and Red Hat themselves recommend disabling THP for database workloads [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-transhuge.html)
2. Set `vm.zone_reclaim_mode=0`. Discussion [here](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2014/06/linux-disables-vmzonereclaimmode-by.html)
3. Set your elevator to deadline from cfq. Red Hat recommends deadline for enterprise storage, which it sounds like you have. Discussion [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/54164)
4. Change from setting `vm.dirty_background_ratio` to `vm.dirty_background_bytes` and `vm.dirty_bytes`.

   The defaults are 10% which given your 384GB of RAM is 38.4 GB of RAM that needs to be dirty before the kernel starts writing it out in the background. I would set the values to 64MB and 50% of the controller RAM, respectively, though that's based on my own anecdotal experience.

Hopefully some of these suggestions work out for you.

Comment: Oh, I forgot as well. Set `vm.swappiness=10`, as recommended [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-tunables.html)

Comment: Thanks!  This is the type of information I was hoping for.  There is so much to consider when running a large Postgres cluster!  I wish PgTune or a similar tool was thorough enough to include these kinds of suggestions.  Even just a tool to help you avoid the most common pitfalls / low hanging fruit would make a big difference.

Comment: The problem with PgTune being this thorough is that it would need to include a lot of OS/Distro specific changes, as well as OS/Distro version changes alongside what suggestions it makes for PostgreSQL, which is outside its scope. Though, poking around more, I did find [tuned](http://servicesblog.redhat.com/2012/04/16/tuning-your-system-with-tuned/) for CentOS which should get you even farther along as well. Glad to be of help, and good luck! =)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried tuned, but it was hard to know what it was messing with, so I felt better changing the settings by hand.